# Observable TextArea defaultValue is whitespace after sendMessage SignalR & Typescript/angular

Tags: angular, typescript, signalr, observable

i'm adapting a basic SignalR Chat function.

The broad context: when a user sends a message, the message get send, but the empty textarea (apart from placeholder) from which is has been sent,
now has a event.currentTarget.defaultValue, consisting of a string of about 13 white spaces.
Ive tried correcting it by setting it to null or '' but still the whitespace stays, hides the placeholder (offcourse).

The original inputfield is a string, in my version i've made a behaviourSubject of it, and added an observable of that behavioursubject

```
txtMessage: string = null; 
txtSubject: BehaviorSubject<string>;
txtStatus: Observable<string>;
this.txtSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>(this.txtMessage);
this.txtStatus = this.txtSubject.asObservable();
this.txtStatus.subscribe(status => {
  if(status !== null && status.length)
    let senderid = this.userid;
    let receiverid = this.selectedChatFriend.id;
    let message = 'typing:' + senderid + ';receiver' + receiverid;
    this.chatService.startedTyping(message);
  }
  if(status == null  && this._selectedChatFriend !== null && this._selectedChatFriend !== undefined){
    let senderid = this.userid;
    let receiverid = this.selectedChatFriend.id;
    let message = 'nottyping:' + senderid + ';receiver' + receiverid;
    this.chatService.stoppedTyping(message);
  }      
});
```

The problem:
When a user sends a message, the receiver gets notified.
On the first message send, all works nice. After the first message, I get the whitespace instead of an empty textarea with a nullvalue and when this user starts typing agagin, the isTyping is not triggered because of the ifstatement on 'starttyping' didn't expect whitespace

```
textinputreceived(event: any){      
  if (event.currentTarget.value.length > 0 && event.inputType == "insertLineBreak"){      
  //event.preventDefault();
  this.sendTextMessage(event.currentTarget.value); 
  }
 
  //filter out anything that is not the txtMessage
  if(event.currentTarget.value.length == 1  && event.inputType == "insertText"){
  //user started typing     
  //triggers the isTyping
  this.txtSubject.next(event.data);    
  
  } else if (event.currentTarget.value == '' && event.inputType == "deleteContentBackward"){
  //user just deleted the only char in the message
  //triggers stopped typing
  this.txtSubject.next(null);
  }      
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="type_msg">  
        <div class="input_msg_write">  
          <textarea type="text"  
                    id="chatbx"                     
                    placeholder="Type a message"
                    class="write_msg" 
                    [value]="txtMessage"                            
                    (input)="textinputreceived($event)"      
                    (keydown.enter)="sendTextMessage($event)">
          </textarea>  
          <button class="msg_send_btn" 
                  type="button"  
                  (click)="sendTextMessage($event)">
                  <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o" aria-hidden="true">
                    <mat-icon style="color:black;margin-top:10px; font-size: 42px; margin-left: -45px;">send</mat-icon>
                  </i>
          </button>  
        </div>  
      </div>
```

and the method to send messages:

```
sendTextMessage(event: any): void {
this.message = new ChatMessage();    
if (this.selectedChatFriend) {
  this.message.messageReceiverId = this.selectedChatFriend.id;
}   
this.message.message = event.currentTarget.value;  
this.txtSubject.next(null);
event.currentTarget.value = null;  
this.txtMessage = null; 
this.message.messageSenderId = this.userid; 
this.message.type = "sent";  
this.message.timeStamp = new Date();      

if(this.message.messageReceiverId && this.message.message.length > 0){
  debugger; //hier pauze is al genoeg  om te werken :o      
  } 
this.chatService.sendMessage(this.message);    
}
```

A couple of strange things happened:

A. I only need 1 keydown on backspace to delete the witespace (13chars), get the placeholder and trigger the isTyping. -I tried faking a JQueryEvent keypressing backspace but didn't get result.

B.If I go in the browsers debug mode on sendmessage and F10 line by line, everything works as planned
-I tried setting a delay, reorgansing the order of the code, still not the desired result

C. in my chat.html, the textarea where the user inputs his messages, I have two methods:
(input)="textinputreceived($event) and
(keydown.enter)="sendTextMessage($event)

if i remove (keydown.enter), if event.currentTarget.value.length > 0 && event.inputType == "insertLineBreak" does not get triggered on the first enter-press, only after i've hit a backspace, it gets triggered (probably because of that whitespace defaultvalue.. but other problems arise :)

I'm not the most confident yet with typescript, so maybe am missing some basic concept (read something about threads maybe).
If you have any idea how to aproach this, I'd be glad to get your input!

other random things I tried:

played around with the value bindings, tried [] and [()],

changes textarea to a div, but no luck..

Update: after a bit of digging & putting everything  in one single line, i managed to reduce the whitespaces to 1char.. have tried manipulating the DOM to remove it, but no success yet..
Strangest thing to me is, this works when I debug line for line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found what was happening!
both (input)="textinputreceived($event)" and (keydown.enter)="sendTextMessage($event)">
trigger a 'enter press', so in debug mode, enterpress get registered, text cleared, message send. If not in debug the enterpress is probably registered after the field has been cleared, hence the whitespace.

simple solution:
event.preventDefault() on both methods!

```
textinputreceived(event: any){      
if (event.inputType == "insertLineBreak"){      
event.preventDefault();    
}


sendTextMessage(event: any): void {
event.preventDefault();
//rest of logic
}
```